# Probability Question doubt

Tags: probability

15 Coupons are numbered from 1......15, 7 Coupons are selected Randomly One at a time With Replacement. The Probability That largest number appearing on selected coupons is 9 is?

How to approach this one?

I know in sample space there will be 15^7 because it is replacement but How can i select that event?

Comment: Hint:  What's the probability that the max is $≤9$?  What's the probability that it is $≤8$?

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of draws whose largest number is exactly $9$, we count the number of draws that have all numbers $9$ or fewer – $9^7$ – and then subtract from that the number of draws that have all numbers $8$ or fewer – $8^7$. The result of this subtraction is the number of draws that have at least one $9$ and no higher numbers, so the final probability is $\frac{9^7-8^7}{15^7}$.